# JasperReports: setHorizontal Alignment

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasperReports Ver 5.6.2. I am trying to set text alignment of a staticText Element using the following function:

```
var HorizontalAlignment = function(jasperElement, design){
    var alignment = design.get("HorizontalAlignment").trim().toLowerCase() + '';
     switch (alignment) {
        case "center":
            println("SETTING HORIZONTAL ALIGNMENT: CENTER");
            jasperElement.setHorizontalAlignment(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAlignment.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER);
            break;
        case "right":
            println("SETTING HORIZONTAL ALIGNMENT: RIGHT");
            jasperElement.setHorizontalAlignment(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAlignment.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_RIGHT);
            break;
        case "left":
            println("SETTING HORIZONTAL ALIGNMENT: LEFT");
            jasperElement.setHorizontalAlignment(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAlignment.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_LEFT);
            break;
        default:
            println("No matching case for alignment: [" + alignment + "]");
    }
}
```

However I am getting the error: org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Can't find method net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignTextElement.setHorizontalAlignment(object). I am doing this using javaScript ES5 in a rhino Script Environment. Have tried everything to bypass this but to no avail. Please help

Expectation is that the static text element should be aligned to the center